# Ember.Js Reflexive Association

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to implement "follower/following" relationship.

app/templates/users.hbs---------------------------

```
{{#each model as |user|}}
   ...
  <button {{action 'follow' user}}>Follow</button>
{{/each}}
```

app/routes/users.js---------------------------

```
 follow(user){
   //currentUser is the one clicking on 'follow' button 
   //and it works.I can successfully alert it's properties.
   currentUser.get('followings').pushObject(user);
 },
```

app/models/user.js-----------------------

```
...
followings: DS.hasMany('user',{inverse: null}),
followers: DS.hasMany('user',{inverse: null}),
```

Now, this solution is causing this error below;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read the property 'modelName' of undefined at assertPolymorphicType.notifyRecordRelationshipAdded
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
followings: DS.hasMany('user', { inverse: 'followers' },
followers: DS.hasMany('user', { inverse: 'followings' },
```